# Woocommerce Make thumbnails fixed height

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a strange problem with thumbnail size on woocommerce site. My thumbnail size for product pages is set to 175 x 169 and for catalog product is 362 x 257 pixels. But as you can see on the link on homepage each image has different height. So is there anyway to force fixed height ? and I would like to know why woocommerce size is not being enforced?

http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/dev/
Ahmar

Comment: Have you regenerated your images after making adjustments to sizes? If you have then you would need to inspect what classes are being applied to your images then add the relevant changes to your CSS

Comment: @LauraClarke Yes I have. Found no solution to the problem. So I have enforced css rule with !important to ensure height

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose "crop" on the image settings?